# Half of disk space missing on RAID1, all disks it seems to be ok

Tags: windows, raid, hard-drive, windows-server-2012, raid1

**Hi there. I have a problem with raid array. I miss it a half.**

My disks layout is

1. 2 x 250 gigabytes velociraptors (Array_0000)
2. 2 x 1TB velociraptors (Array_0001)

....both connected in RAID1. OS is Windows Server 2012.

Array_0001 is formated in ReFS FileSystem.
On Array_0001 is only SQL Server databases. SQL takes about 50 gigabytes. http://d.pr/i/bCiw

Array_0001 has 1TB total capacity and this is problem. Showing only 480 gb free. http://d.pr/i/R3do

I have to be shown the system files, On the disk they are not swap or hibernate file.
This is disk management .....(i have no rights to post other links :( ) 
And this intel rapid storage manager .... (i have no rights to post other links :( ) i need 10 reputation poits. I try add images to comments. **Anyone know this mystery?**

Comment: Intel rapid storage manager http://d.pr/i/8i9X and disk management http://d.pr/i/ikEk it seems to be all ok.

Comment: Well either there are hidden files on the disk or the filesystem really needs some fixing.

Comment: I display all hidden files and anyone does not have 500 gigabytes

Comment: Probably there IS a free space, ReFS has a bit different architecture for counting free space. Try to write some large 500GB+ dummy file :)

Comment: Open the properties for one of your drives in Explorer and click the Shadow Copies tab. Is there any space in use by VSS?

Comment: i have not set shadow copies on these disks.